# How necessary are primary and foreign keys when I truncate all the tables in my database daily?

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

I'm fairly inexperienced at database design, so I am trying to plan my database beforehand as much as possible. This database is to hold information about a VMware environment.

The database has 9 tables currently. Currently the idea is to truncate most of the tables daily and then use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` to populate the tables from CSVs scraped from each VMware vCenter. I'm using auto-increment columns for primary keys, though I could use composite keys consisting of the object's ID and the vCenter name (the object's ID is only unique per vCenter) if I were more confident in my database knowledge.

Since most of the tables will be truncated daily, is there any benefit in using foreign keys rather than just using `WHERE` logic? Are there other questions I should be asking that I might not know to ask?

Comment: What does truncation have to do with primary and foreign keys? And the WHERE logic?

Comment: Foreign keys are more about integrity of the data.  Child records without a parent don't happen if foreign keys are used.

Comment: As for primary keys, NEVER go without them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PRIMARY KEYs` are important; use them.  Since there seems to be a 'natural' PK, use it instead of a surrogate `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

`FOREIGN_KEYs` are not a requirement.  They do, however, create helper `INDEXes`, but you could create those without FKs`.

If the data is changing every day, what would you do if an FK failed?

Using `TRUNCATE`, then `LOAD` leaves the table empty for a brief time; if that is a problem, do this:

```
CREATE TABLE x LIKE real;  -- or use a regular CREATE.
LOAD DATA ... INTO x;
RENAME TABLE real TO old, x to REAL;
DROP TABLE old;
```